# Ajax return not show on page source Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with AJAX return values. The returned data is not showing on my page's source code.

This is my controller code in Codeigniter:

```
public function get_rooms(){
    $rooms_selected = $this->input->get('q', TRUE);
    $this->load->model('roomreservation_model');
    $room_numbers = $this->roomreservation_model->numberofroom($rooms_selected);
    echo '<select class="form-control" name="room_number" id="room_number">';

    foreach ($room_numbers as $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$value->room_number.'">'.$value->room_number.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Room Detail</h2>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 form-label">
        <label for="Room Type">Room Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="roomtype" id="roomtype" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a Room Type</option>
            <option value="King Suit">King Suit</option>
            <option value="Suit One">Suit One</option>
            <option value="Suit Two">Suit Two</option>
            <option value="Suit Three">Suit Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 form-label">
        <label for="Room Type">Room Avaiable</label>
        <div id="txtHint">
            <b style="color:#6E6E6E">Select Room type then show Avaiable Rooms</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select a room type (from my select dropdown), an AJAX request is made which returns with all rooms available. Its works fin, but the problem is when I check the browser's source code. It does not show the source of the Available Rooms.

Comment: Can you add your javascript and ajax call here?

Comment: where's your AJAX code?? Please provide your JS where the function `showUser()` is shown

Comment: In order for us to help you, you need to provide your JS/AJAX code (where the function `showUser()` is shown), and  your Model's `numberofroom()` method,  Once you do that, we will be able to know where the problem lies.

Comment: thanks for reply i say ajax work fine its return value when i select the room type (from my select dropdown) , its show value on <div id="txtHint">

        </div>  but problem is its not show on browser source page

Comment: I dont think most browsers view source will show HTML modified with Javascript. In Firefox you can use FireBug to view the generated HTML

Comment: in firebug show it but in browser source page not show . above code if you see we get result <select class="form-control" name="room_number" id="room_number"> in this name room_number we want to insert in database but problem is its show on it but not show on source then when insert in database its store 0